# Java - inner ArrayList loop not doing intended function

Tags: java, arraylist, size, lastindexof

This code works as expected: It iterates the outer ArrayList (coverage), and iterates inner ArrayLists (covArrayList), and when an inner ArrayList contains "noBaseData", 5 empty elements are added to the end.

```
    //add empty elements for coverage data when noBaseData found:
    for(int i = 0; i<coverage.size(); i++)
    {
        if(coverage.get(i).contains("noBaseData"))
        {
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
            {
                coverage.get(i).add("");
            }//end for(int j)
        } //end if(!coverage)
    } //end for(i)
```

This code does NOT work as expected:

```
    //add empty elements when coveragy by only one base station:
    for(int i = 0; i<coverage.size(); i++)
    {
        if(coverage.get(i).size()<6);
        {
            for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
            {
                coverage.get(i).add("");
            }//end for(int j)
        }//end if(coverage)
```

Desired Outcome:
It iterates the outer ArrayList (coverage), and iterates inner ArrayLists (covArrayList), and when an inner ArrayList has a .size() less than 6 (also have tried 5 & 7), two empty elements are added to the end.

Actual Outcome:
It adds two empty elements to every inner ArrayList.

Inserting "System.out.println(coverage.get(i).size());" BEFORE 'if(coverage.get(i).size()<6)' returns the proper size of the inner ArrayLists (either 5 or 7).

Inserting "System.out.println(coverage.get(i).toString();" BEFORE 'if(coverage...);' corroborates the .size() reported.

Putting 'System.out...' AFTER the loop returns .size()/toString() with the empty elements added.

ArrayList coverage sample contents:

> [[AA-123-12345-SP1.SSF, , 100, 100, guug04914003.zip], [AA-123-23451-SP1.SSF, noBaseData, , , , , ], [AA-123-23451-SP2.SSF, , 100, 4, guug04914003.zip, 100, guug04914022.zip]]

"if(coverage.get(i).lastIndexOf()<6)" won't compile. Message:

> .java:208: error: method lastIndexOf in interface List cannot be applied to given types;
>               if(coverage.get(i).lastIndexOf()<4);
>                                 ^
>     required: Object
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>     where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in interface List
>   1 error

I'm stumped. Anyone have any thoughts?

EDIT: rgettman pointed out my mistake. I have a semicolon after my if statement.
I bow my head in shame!!

Comment: Have you checked to see what the `size`s are?

Comment: lastIndexOf takes a character as an argument... I'm not sure what you're trying to do with it there

Comment: Lose that semicolon following your `if` condition; the semicolon _is_ the body of the `if` condition.

Comment: also this is not iterating the "inner ArrayList"? I don't see 'covArrayList' anywhere in your code?

Comment: @rgettman, You're the PERSON!!

Comment: @kay, Thanks for your input - I was initially trying to misuse .lastIndexOf, then dropped it when I realized that. Thanks!
The ArrayLists are declared at the beginning of the script, as global variables; they get initialized when regexes are parsed into them.